# Progress declaration at the Form level gives an exception

Tags: c#, async-await

In a WPF window, *started within a Console application*, I tried this example for the use of IProgress in async-await:

```
namespace Test
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Main : Window
{
    // class level declaration
    Progress<string> Progress1;

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       // initialization of class level field
        Progress1 = new Progress<string>(value =>
        {
            Print(value);
        });
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Print("Start test");

        // local variable 
        Progress<string> Progress2 = new Progress<string>(value =>
        {
            Print(value);
        });

        // interface (normally Progress1/2 would be passed as a parameter)
        // Progress2 works fine, Progress1 gives an exception
        var progress = Progress1 as IProgress<string>;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
            {
                if (progress != null) progress.Report("\nStage " + i);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });

        Print("\nCompleted.");
    }

    void Print(string text)
    {
        //Output is a WPF TextBlock
        Output.Inlines.Add(new Run(text) { Foreground = Brushes.Blue, FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal });
    }
}
```

The local variable `Progress2` works fine: the callback is in the UI thread.
The class level field `Progress1` gives an exception. This callback is clearly in the background thread.

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

It probably has to do with the way anonymous functions and callbacks work.
Can somebody explain the problem?

EDIT
The problem is not reproduciblein a normal WPF solution.
It is reproducible in a Console application where the WPF windows is started as in:

```
Application app = new Application ();
app.Run(new Main());
```

In that case `Synchronization.Current == null` in the constructor and it is `!= null` in e.g. the `Loaded` event. As explained in the answers and comments.

Comment: Unable to repro. If I move the declaration to class scope, I get a compiler error. If I move the declaration to the class constructor, it works fine. Please post the actual code that is causing the problem.

Comment: I edited the question with exact code - is it not reproducable?

Comment: No. It works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @StephenCleary It is only reproducible in a console application that starts the WPF window (see my edit).

Comment: That's because you're calling `Main.Main` before starting the application's main loop `Application.Run`. Thus your `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null` as Hans pointed out. If you must host in a console app, then you should do the initialization in an event handler (like `Window.Loaded`) instead of the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, buy Microsoft a cigar for building this diagnostic into Winforms because this would otherwise a *completely* undebuggable problem, one that crashes your code only occasionally.

This is an *initialization order* problem, it is caused by your Progress variable being initialized *too soon*.  Keep in mind what the Progress<> class does, it knows how to run the target of the delegate you pass on the "right thread".  Specially, you want it to run on your UI thread so you can safely update the label.  Progress<> does so by making a copy of `SynchronizationContext.Current`, using it later to run the delegate target with its Post() method.

Problem is, the `Current` property does not have a value yet.  That happens a few microseconds later, when the Form base class constructor runs.  Progress<> has copied a null, the only thing it can do now is to run the Post() method target on a thread pool thread.  Kaboom!

The fix is simple:

```
Progress<string> Progress;

public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    Progress  = new Progress<string>(value => {
        label.Text = value;
    });
}
```

Now it is initialized later, Synchronization.Current has a value.

Comment: At first I thought you are completely right. Tonight I tried it again and the problem remains even when initialized in the constuctor (I use wpf). Edited the question with exact code.

Comment: Hmm, avoid using the word "form" when you ask a WPF question.  Debug it, set a breakpoint on the statement and inspect the value of System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.  If it is null then we'll need garlic and silver bullets.

Comment: Okay, the next thing I'd do is set a breakpoint on the Text property assignment and try to make sense of the Call Stack debugger window.  Good luck with it, bring garlic.

Comment: I discoverd that the problem only occurs in a console application that starts the WPF window (compare the edit). A bit late to discover that, sorry. The thread just fails at `VerifyAccess` of the dispatcher.`

Comment: @Gerard As you can see in your own `Main` method, you run the constructor before starting the message loop.  You need to initialize `Progress` after you already have a message loop, which means running it after the constructor has finished.